# Batch users creation

Tags: user-registration

I would like to share a document with about 140 users after password authentication and I want to avoid to create manually all the 140 accounts. Is it possible to create them quickly?

**UPDATE**: usernames to add are stored into a text file. The question is focused on the batch users creation because I will create a password-protected area where all the users will access to download the document.

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to batch create users or share a document? If it's the latter, how do you want to share the document?

Comment: I think he is referring to users only - but what form those users currently exist in (DB, CSV etc) is not stated.

Comment: You are right, the question was not very clear. I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small code I wrote to batch create generic users

```
<?php $lock = true; //true = disabled (locked)

if(!$lock) { // if not locked
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

    $last_registered_user = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $new_id = $last_registered_user->ID + 1;
    $limit = false; // extra lock

    while($new_id <= $limit) {
        wp_create_user( 'user_'.$new_id, 'changeme', 'user'.$new_id.'@example.com' );
        $new_id++;
    }
} else { // if locked ?>
    <h5>This script is locked to prevent accidental use.</h5>
<?php
}
?>
```

## Setup

A couple things to do:

1. Change unlock the script by setting `$lock` to false.
2. Change the path to `wp-load.php`.
3. Change `$limit` to the number of users you want to create.

## Use

This script will create `$limit` number of users with the username `user_andTheirID` and their e-mail address `userTheirID@example.com`. To edit the username, once the users have been created, you will have to edit the database itself.

## Extra

If you want users to change their passwords from the default, `changeme`, try the [Force Password Change](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-password-change/) plugin by Simon Blackbourn. This will require users to change their password on their first log in. Make sure you install this plugin **BEFORE** you run the batch create, otherwise the right values will not be created for the existing users.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a plugin to do batch import.

This [one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-users-from-csv/) allows you to import records from a CSV file.

Comment: Please try to avoid link only answers. At the very least, try to explain what the plugin does in more detail than the name of the plugin itself reveals. Why do you think the OP wants to import from CVS?

Answer (score 0):

Importing WordPress users from a CSV file is easily possible with this free [WordPress user import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com).